A property related to the orthocenter and the Euler circle in a triangle
This is actually a property I found out while fooling around with Geogebra.

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with altitudes $AD, BE, CF$ and orthocenter $H$, circumcircle $(O)$. Then the circumcircle of $\triangle DEF$ is the Euler circle of $\triangle ABC$. Let $T$ be an arbitrary point on that circle. $HT$ intersects $(O)$ at $J$. Then $T$ is the midpoint of $HJ$.


Below is my proof for it, and I found it too simple for this property, so please point it out for me if I'm wrong at any stage. And if you got any other proof, please share it with me.
Thank you.

Let $I, P$ are the intersection of $AH, CF$ and the Euler circle
respectively.
WLOG, assume that $T$ is on the small arc $DI$ and $AB < AC$.
Let $K$ be the intersection of $CF$ and $(O)$. Then it's well-known
that $I, P, F$ are the midpoints of $AH, CH, KH$ respectively (thus
they are the special cases of this problem).
Let $J'$ be the reflection of $H$ via $T$ then $FT, IT, IP$ are the
mid-segments of the triangles $J'KH, J'AH, HAC$ correspondingly. Thus
$TF\parallel J'K, TI\parallel J'A, IP \parallel AC$.  Therefore
$\widehat{J'KH} = \widehat{TFH}, \widehat{J'AH}=\widehat{TIH}$,
$\widehat{HAC}=\widehat{HIP}$.
So $\widehat{J'KC} + \widehat{J'AC} = \widehat{J'KH} + \widehat{J'AC}
> = \widehat{TFH}+\widehat{TIH}+\widehat{HAC} = \widehat{TFH}+\widehat{TIP}$.
The last one is equal to $\pi$ for $TFPI$ is cyclic. Thus $J'KCA$ is
also cyclic, and then $J'\equiv J\Rightarrow T$ is the midpoint of
$HJ$.


Your WLOG isn't valid for the $AB < AC$ condition. If $T$ was chosen to fall on the largest side, then it won't be satisfied.

(Esp if writing up a proof at a contest) IMO You should explicitly show the $F$ is indeed the midpoint of $KH$.

@CalvinLin: If $T$ was chosen to fall on the largest side, then I would choose $K$ to be the intersection of $BE, (O)$ and $P$ to be the midpoint of $BH$, so that the proof remains valid?

Note that I'm being pedantic about the assumption of $AB < AC$ not holding, so we cannot "without loss of generality". Even if the proof is valid, the problem statement does not follow because the conditions are not satisfied. $\quad$  It's not clear to me if you used $AB < AC$ at all. I don't think you did (unless theres some weird angle chasing that depends on how the diagram is drawn up, but I don't think that's that case). If so, I'd just remove that condition completely.

Consider homothety/expansion around $H$ with scale factor 2.
By checking vertices $A, B, C$, we see that it brings the nine-point circle to the circumcircle.
Hence $HJ = 2HT$ as desired.
Note: Reading through your solution, you are essentially expressing the above idea, in a slightly longer manner.

Yes, the fact (and the proof) that the circumcircle is the image of the Euler circle by homothety $\frak{H}$$(H,2)$ is seen in some places, but should be more known.


the (better known ?) fact that the symmetrical points of the orthocenter wrt the sides belong to the circumcircle.

